# Calling web service from compact framework too slow

Tags: web-services, compact-framework

i have an application with CF3.5
Calling of simple webMethod like
bool Ping(Guid id){return true;}
takes ~ 1.8 sec (windows client answer takes ~ 0.3 sec)

As i read, there is way to optimize speed by gzip - but it seems here we have nothig to compress...
Is there any other ideas to increase speed?

thanks

Comment: How long is a command-line ping to service?  Can you track down the bottleneck whether it's in the application or in your network?

Comment: Do both clients use the same network to connect to the service?

Answer (score 0):

When calling Web Services from the Compact Framework, the first call is always painfully slow as the CF has to JIT and instatiate all of the proxy pieces required to make the call.  Typically you'll see a slow first call and then reasonable call times after that.  A typical workaround is to have the app spin up a worker thread at startup that makes a call to the web service - even if it just calls a stub method - to get all of that work done in the background before you need to make a "real" call.

Comment: It seems problem is with network. Command-line ping from EDGE conn. takes ~ 0.5-0.8sec, when i tried to connect throw WiFi - speed increased twice...

Comment: So you're saying WiFi is faster than EDGE, and that's surprises you?  EDGE is what, maybe 100kbps on a nice day and WiFi is probably 54Mbps.